# Azure AD certicate error on IOS native Application

Tags: ios, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-authentication

I have an application which uses AZURE AD authentication. But when:

1. The user walks through app setup experience.
2. The ADAL Sign-in page appears, on which the user enters their email address and then clicks Next.
   On clicking next after entering the email, the following message appears on the screen "Select a certificate that you want to use for authentication. If you cancel the operation, please close your browser and try again" and the app closes.
   [Certificate message][Select an certificate][1]

However, when I login with safari, I am able to successfully login, but on native app the authentication fails. Note I have these certificates pre installed on my device, as i have installed a profile, these certificates are installed with it.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Fml.png

Comment: What conditional access rules are set up for mobile applications?  Is the device managed by intune? Is the Authenticator app installed?  Is your ADAL using brokered authentication?

Comment: @Paulw11 Authenticator app is installed

Comment: And have you set the parameter for brokered authentication?

Comment: @Paulw11 Please could you let me know more about it?